# Post a Form without reload page using jQuery validate plugin within multiple forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

A front-end page contains multiple form with the same class-name , 
because i wanna each row in table is a form , user can submit the row.
after validate , the row can be removed. all there things done in javascript.

but however , it doesn't work.
is there any substitution for the same task ?
thank you all in advance.

[image]

[image]

```
<table width="800">
    <tbody>
    <form class=myform id=form_13 action="back_end.php"><tr id="13" ~~~~~></from>
    <form ...><tr id="21" ~~~~></form>
    </tbody>
    </table>


    (function ($) { 
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.myform').each(function(){

    sn = $(this).attr("sn");

    var $form_obj = $(this);

    $form_obj.validate({

    debug: false, // submit the form

    rules: {
    bill_sn: {
    required: true,         
    }               
    }, // rules ends

    messages: {
    bill_sn:"請輸入匯款序號",              
    },

    submitHandler: function(form) {

    $.post('admin_order_validate.php', $form_obj.serialize(), function(data) {

    $("#results").html(data);                   
    $("#div_"+sn).remove();
    console.log("remove div_"+sn);
    console.log("sn:"+sn);
    console.log("data"+data);
    })
    .error(function() { alert("error"); });


    return false; // stop going to the action page
    }       


    });//validate ends

    });
    }); // $(document ready)
    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: Would you give us a little guideline there? I'm unable to speak Chinese. Where does your code step in action?

Comment: It would help if you posted your javascript code.